# Analyse the Server response while testing an Application manually

Tags: performance-testing, manual-testing, server-response

I have an Web application which I have to measure the Performance from the Server response of that application while testing it manually in several machine.

How can I do it. Do we have any tool to measure the Server Response time of a Web Application while performing the manual testing on several machine.

Thanks,
Udhay S

Answer (score 1):

Udhay,

JMETER provides you all necessary performance graphs from which you can get the server response. Its easy to use and you can increase the load to test the server response.
In JMETER you have a list of reports - Aggregate graph, Spline Visualizer graph and a summary report explaining the server response.

Answer (score 0):

A stopwatch? Seriously, if you are running manual tests then the best, most accurate and the most purely subjective way to record how long it *appears* to take for a page to load is to use a stopwatch wired to the human brain. Until someone can invent a computer that can pass a Turing test this is as good as it gets.

If you feel like you need to automate things then automate the test first, and then think about automating recording response time.

Comment: Thanks for replying with exactly the same as I was having in my mind.